# Usage of central documentation system for TeXLive distribution (texdoc)

Tags: installing, texlive, texdoc

Recently, when peeking over the shoulder of someone who has years of experience working with TeX, I saw him type something into the terminal that caused a pdf with the documentation for a LaTeX package we were working with to open. I asked if he had a central utility for finding the documentation for a package, his answer was: "Yes, it's called `texdoc`, look into it." We then kept doing our thing, and since his time for me is limited, I didn't further inquire and figured I'd find out on my own.

And so I tried, but can't seem to get the hang of it. I have a full working installation of TeX Live 2012 set up, and get this output:

```
$ texdoc
/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux/texdoc:7: module 'texdoc.main' not found:
no field package.preload['texdoc.main']
[kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'texdoc.main'
[kpse C searcher] file not found: 'texdoc.main'
[kpse All-in-one searcher] file not found: 'texdoc'
```

So apparently something is missing or not configured, as far as I can tell. I made sure that I had also installed the documentation, and `tlmgr` confirmed this. Considering this mentor of mine is already an older gentleman, is this software maybe outdated? Or (what seems more plausible) am I just doing it wrong?

#### Follow-up problem 1 [solved]

Thanks to David Carlisle's answer, I seem to have resolved the issue of `texdoc` not working properly. However, now all I get is the following:

```
~$ texdoc geometry
Sorry, no documentation found for geometry.
If you are unsure about the name, try searching CTAN's TeX catalogue at
http://ctan.org/search.html#byDescription.
```

**EDIT/SOLVED:** Since I had installed the `medium` scheme originally, there was no documentation for all the packages that were downloaded then. A reinstallation of TeXLive fixed that problem.

Comment: For the heck of it, try `texdoc geometry`

Comment: I get the same error as described on the post above...

Comment: based on your update, it appears that at least some documentation has not been loaded. try this test that should list multiple possibilities for a name: `texdoc -l amsmath` (the `-l` is key). on the system i'm using, this returns 15 files, with full path, and asks the user to choose one (or not). `amsmath` is a "required" package, so if documentation has been installed, you should get a "sensible" response; if nothing is found, then it's *very* likely that the `medium` scheme did not install documentation. not sure whether it's possible to install *only* documentation files separately.

Comment: @Barbara: Thanks for chiming in. I get the same error than the one in the update: "no documentation found". Is documentation usually installed in the TeX Live installation directory? Any idea where I could look myself to see if there are any documentation files?

Comment: i've taken a quick look at the [on-line tex live installation documentaion](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) amd it's not clear to me that it's possible to download just the package documentation; but you might look there yourself.  (the installation i'm using is "complete", so i don't know the details of selective installation.)  the main tex live tree has several branches.  you can determine from a log file what the `tex/latex` branch is; there *should be* a parallel branch `doc/latex`, and package documentation should be there.  if that branch is missing, no doc. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) i will ask the tex live maintenance group if it's possible to selectively download package documentation, whether that documentation is included in the "medium" download, and a few other relevant questions, and suggest including that information clearly in the documentation, if it's not there already.  but it's too late for tex live 2013.

Comment: This is now a completely different question, so it is better asked as a new question.

Comment: @mafp You're right, I was just doing that... :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I followed David Carlisle's advice and navigated to the link he provided. I am posting my solution as a separate answer to have it "on-site" and not only as a link.

It turns there were a couple of things wrong with my installation of TeX Live:

- I hadn't installed the `perl-tk` package on my Unix-based system, which is apparently a good thing to have when you work with a manual TeX Live installation; most importantly it enables the GUI for the `tlmgr` or "TeX Live Manager". On Debian-derived systems (all *buntus), this is quickly fixed by running

  ```
  sudo apt-get install perl-tk
  ```

  in a terminal.
- I still had an old preinstalled version of `luatex` roaming around in my system. This is relevant, since `texdoc` is a Lua script or uses a Lua script in some way (Lua is a programming language, refer to the link in David Carlisle's answer and read the complete email exchange to read more about this). Since my PATH variable was set up as

  ```
  PATH="...:/usr/bin/:....:/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux"
  ```

  when I executed `texdoc` my system first found the old version of `luatex` which wasn't finding the necessary files since it lived in another directory than my actual TeX Live installation. This was fixed by two easy steps:

  1. Removing all traces of the old TeX Live distribution preinstalled on my system (by running `sudo apt-get remove texlive-*` on Debian-based systems)
  2. Correcting the PATH environment variable so that my TeX Live installation directory precedes any other directory where there may be TeX-related binaries. This is done by changing either the file `.pam_environment` (for the current user session) or by editing `/etc/environment" with sudo privileges (for all users).

After completing these steps, everything worked as expected: `texdoc` tried to find the documentation for the package you tell it to...  it just couldn't find anything. This was because I had originally installed the `medium` scheme and this included no documentation. A reinstall of TexLive, using the scheme `complete`, resolved this issue.

Answer (score 19):

something is wrong with your installation:

```
texdoc longtable
```

is supposed to open the `longtable` package and

```
texdoc
```

on its own is supposed to echo some usage help that starts out like

```
$ texdoc
Usage: texdoc [OPTION]... NAME...
  or:  texdoc ACTION

Try to find appropriate TeX documentation for the specified NAME(s).
Alternatively, perform the given ACTION and exit.

Current settings: --view, --interact (default).

Options:
  -w, --view            Use view mode: start a viewer. (default)
  -m, --mixed           Use mixed mode (view or list).
```

However google suggests that error has been seen before.

This thread ends with a happy ending, perhaps your problem is similar:

http://tug.org/pipermail/texdoc/2011q3/000281.html

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth --- and for those who do not have a TeX Live installation --- there is also an [online version](http://www.texdoc.net/) developed and maintained by frequent contributors to this site.  Like `texdoc` itself, a very useful resource that should not be overlooked.

The interface is so simple that it needs no explanation, but the basic principle is that the URL `http://texdoc.net/pkg/<packagename>` should link you to the package's (main) documentation.  Thus,

```
http://texdoc.net/pkg/geometry
```

offers me the chance to download the `geometry` documentation.  (I assume if you have your browser set up with a pdf plug-in, it will just display the PDF.)